# Pass result of the command to exec

Tags: bash, exec

I have a kind of "bash newbie" question: how do I pass the result output of one command to exec. The result of the first command is the name of other command, so exec should be able to execute it.

Comment: Are you sure you want `exec`? If you just want to execute the result of a command, you don't need `exec`, just run it directly. What `exec` does is *exit the current shell* and replace it with the specified program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). A contrived (and rather useless) example:

```
exec $(echo whoami)
```

The `$(…)` will be replaced with the output of the command within. There's also the variant with backticks (`), but it's not recommended [for various reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).